# MVC Client-Side Validation for EditorFor in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller

So I have a view with the following structure (this isn't the actual code, but a summary):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTableBody">
      @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Components.Count; i++)
      {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyCollection[i])
      }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button id="btnAddRow" type="button">MyButton</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" />
}

@section scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/MyJs.js")
}
```

The EditorFor is rendering markup that represents rows bound to properties in MyCollection. Here's a sample snippet of how the editor template looks:

```html
@model MyProject.Models.MyCollectionClass

<tr>
  <td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, Model.AvailableTypes)
  </td>
</tr>
```

Basically, my problem is that the client-side validation won't fire for the elements inside of the editor template as it should. Could someone point me in the right direction of where I might be going wrong with this.

Also, please note that the following is set in my web.config.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

and also MyCollectionClass has proper [Require] annotations on the properties that shall be enforced. Another thing to note is that checking

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
}
```

Returns false, as expected, if the required fields aren't right. The problem there is that I want client-side validation and not server-side. One of my other pages is implementing jQuery validation, but does not contain all the nesting that this scenario does and thus it works correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add jquery unobtrusive validation scripts ? Can I see the scripts included in your page ?

Comment: Remove the `for` loop - it just needs to be `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyCollection)` - the `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and is smart enough to render the correct html for each item in the collection. But you code does not make sense since the `for` loop is for property `Components` not property `MyCollection` (is that a typo?)

Comment: In any case you should include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each property in the `EditorTemplate` so its clear to the user which row has the error (and the summary should then be `@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`)

Comment: As Stephen mentions, EditorTemplates automatically iterate over collections.  You don't, and shouldn't do it yourself unless you have a very specific reason to do so (which your code doesn't show that this is the case).  Not only does this make your html cleaner, it will ensure all the correct wiring is done for the template context and field names are named correctly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke This was a typo on my part. I was attempting to use generic names (i.e. MyCollection) but ended up typing the actual collection (i.e. Components). Thank you and others for letting me know that @Html.EditorFor() is smart enough to iterate through an IEnumerable. I'm at home right now and the code is at work and so I will verify that this fixes my issue in the morning. Hopefully one of these suggestions fixes the problem.

Comment: @GiuDo Yes, the unobtrusive validation scripts are being loaded. As a matter of fact, the page that the user sees before this table is validating correctly. The difference is the previous page is more straight forward, i.e. a simple form whose elements bind directly to the page's view model.

Comment: So I removed the foreach loop from inside the tbody of the view and placed a for loop inside the editortemplate. I also made the model for the editor template @model List<MyProject.Models.MyCollectionClass> and used a for loop inside the editortemplate. This solved the immediate problem of the validation not working when the form is submitted but another problem remains. When I add a new row to the table (by posting back to the server and receiving a new row) the new row does not validate. Only the original items loaded in the table are validated. Any suggestions here?

Comment: @BrandonAvant, You should **NOT** have a loop inside an `EditorTemplate` The template needs to be `@model MyCollectionClass` (exactly as your have it in your question) and in the view you just use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Components)` The `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` will render the html for each item in your collection.

Comment: And as far as the validation of the new rows not working, you need to ask a new question and show the relevant code for how you add a new row. For example if you using ajax to add dynamic content you need to reparse the validator

Comment: When I change the template back to MyCollectionClass and simply use the editor as you described (passing in the whole collection), I get the error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Web.Models.MyCollectionClass.MyCollectionClass]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Web.Models.MyCollectionClass.MyCollectionClass'.

Comment: @BrandonAvant, Impossible (unless you also have other errors in your code).

Comment: Include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each  `@Html.EditorFor()`       . Hope this link will help you -->https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/simple-mvc-application-using-standard-validation/

Answer (score 2):

From what I Have learnt MVC Doesn't really provide 'out of the box' client side validation.
there are third party options but I prefer to do my own thing so I handballed the whole thing in JavaScript.
To compound matters with the EditorFor doesn't allow adding html attributes like other Helper Methods.

My Fix for this was fairly complex but I felt comprehensive, I hope you find it as helpful as I have

First Overload the HtmlHelper EditorFor in .Net

```
public static HtmlString EditBlockFor<T, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, Expression<System.Func<T, TValue>> prop, bool required)
    {   
        string Block = "";
        Block += "<div class='UKWctl UKWEditBox' " +
            "data-oldvalue='" + helper.ValueFor(prop) + "' " +
            "data-required='" + required.ToString() + ">";
        Block += helper.EditorFor(prop);
        Block += "</div>";

        return new HtmlString(Block);
    }
```

add the new editBlockfor in razor view (just as you are) but alter the Begin Form method to add a Name and id to the form element so you can identify it later

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "MyDataForm", id = "MyDataForm" }))
```

Then when the User Clicks Save, Run the validation method from JavaScript

```
function validate(container)    {

    var valid = true;
    //use jquery to iterate your overloaded editors controls fist and clear any old validation
    $(container).find(".UKWctl").each(function (index) { clearValidation($(this)); });
    //then itterate Specific validation requirements 
    $(container).find(".UKWctl[data-required='True']").each(function (index) {
        var editobj = getUKWEdit(this);
        if (editobj.val() == "") {
            valid = false;
            //use this Method to actually add the errors to the element
            AddValidationError(editobj, 'This field, is required');
            //now add the Handlers to the element to show or hide  the valdation popup
            $(editobj).on('mouseenter', function (evt) { showvalidationContext(editobj, evt); });
            $(editobj).on('mouseout', function () { hidevalidationContext(); });
            //finally add a new class to the element so that extra styling can be added to indicate an issue 
        $(editobj).addClass('valerror');
    }
    });
    //return the result so the methods can be used as a bool
    return valid;
}
```

Add Validation Method

```
function AddValidationError(element, error) {
    //first check to see if we have a validation attribute using jQuery
    var errorList = $(element).attr('data-validationerror');
    //If not Create a new Array() 
    if (!errorList || errorList.length < 1) {
        errorList = new Array();
    } else {
        //if we have, parse the Data from Json
        var tmpobj = jQuery.parseJSON(errorList);
        //use jquery.Map to convert it to an Array()
       errorList = $.map(tmpobj, function (el) { return el; });
    }
   if ($.inArray(error, errorList) < 0) {
        // no point in add the same Error twice (just in case)
        errorList.push(error);
    }
    //then stringyfy the data backl to JSON and add it to a Data attribute     on your element using jQuery
     $(element).attr('data-validationerror', JSON.stringify(errorList));
}
```

Lastly Show and hide the actual Errors,
In order to facilitate this easily I slipped in a little div element to the _Layout.html

```
    <div id="ValidataionErrors" title="" style="display:none">
        <h3 class="error">Validation Error</h3>
        <p>This item contatins a validation Error and Preventing Saving</p>
        <p class="validationp"></p>
    </div>
```

Show

```
var tipdelay;
function showvalidationContext(sender, evt)
{
    //return if for what ever reason the validationError is missing
    if ($(sender).attr('data-validationerror') == "") return;
    //Parse the Error to an Object 
    var jsonErrors = jQuery.parseJSON($(sender).attr('data-validationerror'));
    var errorString = '';
//itterate the Errors from the List and build an 'ErrorString'
    for (var i = 0; i <= jsonErrors.length; i++)
    {
        if (jsonErrors[i]) {
            //if we already have some data slip in a line break
            if (errorString.length > 0) { errorString += '<br>'; }
            errorString += jsonErrors[i];
        }
    }
//we don't want to trigger the tip immediatly so delay it for just a moment 
    tipdelay = setTimeout(function () {
        //find the p tag tip if the tip element  
        var validationError = $('#ValidataionErrors').find('.validationp');
        //then set the html to the ErrorString 
        $(validationError).html(errorString);
        //finally actually show the tip using jQuery, you can use the     evt to find the mouse position 
        $('#ValidataionErrors').css('top', evt.clientY);
        $('#ValidataionErrors').css('left', evt.clientX);
        //make sure that the tip appears over everything 
        $('#ValidataionErrors').css('z-index', '1000');
        $('#ValidataionErrors').show();
    }, 500);
}
```

Hide (Its much easier to hide)

```
function hidevalidationContext() {
    //clear out the tipdelay
    clearTimeout(tipdelay);
    //use jquery to hide the popup
    $('#ValidataionErrors').css('top', '-1000000px');
    $('#ValidataionErrors').css('left', '-1000000px');
    $('#ValidataionErrors').css('z-index', '-1000');
    $('#ValidataionErrors').hide();
}
```

for usage you can try some thing like

```
function save()
{
    if (validate($("#MyDataForm")))
    {
         $("#MyDataForm").submit();   
    }
    else {
        //all the leg has been done this stage so perhaps do nothing
    }
}
```

here is My Css for the validation Popup

```
#ValidataionErrors {
    display: block; 
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}

#ValidataionErrors h3 { border: 2px solid red; }
.valerror { box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px red; }
```